# How to Get Video Thumbnail from onActivityResult Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, video-thumbnails

Below is my code, I'm getting a null from ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
takePicture.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 4);
```

My OnResultActivity Code for Video File Pick Intent:

```
if(requestCode == 4) {
    Uri selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedVideoUri.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    Log.i("Video URI, ", String.valueOf(bitmap));
}
```

and also please help me how to get thumbnail from recorded video intent

```
Intent takeVideo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takeVideo, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: are you facing any error ?

Comment: Yeah! @Moudiz I'm getting NULL Bitmap from ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() and Path is looking like this content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/2/mediaKey%3A%2FAF1QipPxxGACJYs83m_I4qJ0ZWWUuTkYkZRmd7mMoz-Q/ACTUAL/1273675962

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after some research I noticed that the [file path](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) shouldn't be uri

you should have something like this

```
final String noturipath = getRealPathFromUri();

Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(noturipath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

then create a method

```
    public string getRealPathFromUri (final Uri content)
    {
 // get intent from activity and added it here

    Uri uri;
    String stringUri;
    stringUri = uri.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I cant understand how to implement it.